# Remove rows based on multiple column conditions in R (duplicates and min/max values)

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to remove rows from a data frame based on multiple conditions from different columns.

My data frame looks something like this:

```
# reproducible example
df <- data.frame (id  = c("id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2"),
                  key = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a"),
                  start = c(161, 161, 162, 353, 354, 823, 823, 824, 824, 1170, 1170, 1172),
                  end = c(205, 228, 166, 408, 408, 831, 837, 829, 830, "1176", "1194", "1194"))
```

```
id   key   start   end
id1  a     161     205
id1  a     161     228
id1  a     162     166
id1  b     353     408
id1  b     354     408
id2  a     823     831
id2  a     823     837
id2  a     824     829
id2  a     824     830
id2  a     1170    1176
id2  a     1170    1194
id2  a     1172    1194
```

I would like to keep the rows with the same `id` and `key`, but with the condition that the `start` value is greater or equal (>=) and/or the `end` value is less or equal (<=) compared to the duplicates.

So, at the end I would like to get one row per `id` and `key` with the longest range: minimum value for `start` and maximum value for `end`.

Thus, the final data frame would look like this:

```
id   key   start   end
id1  a     161     228
id1  b     353     408
id2  a     823     837
id2  a     1170    1194
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could get the `min/max` after grouping by 'id' and 'key'.  If there are multiple ranges, we may need to create another grouping based on the difference in the previous end and the the 'start' value

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(id, key) %>%
   mutate(grp = cumsum(lag(end, default = first(end)) - start < 0)) %>% 
   group_by(grp, .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  id    key   start   end
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 id1   a       161   228
2 id1   b       353   408
3 id2   a       823   837
4 id2   a      1170  1194
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this didn't work in my case, since the output only gives one row per 'id' and 'key', and in my original data frame I have multiple ranges for the same 'id' and 'key'. I modified the reproducible example, so it is closer to what I have. Do you know what can I do in this case?